# How average can be calculated from database in php on basis of date

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to calculate the average of data retrieved from mysql database on basis of date. For example records are saved in database on daily basis with storing its date the average method will calculate overall average but can it be possible to calculate on basis of date stored in database

Comment: Yes. It is. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group records by date and calculate average of a column.

Example:

```
SELECT date, AVG(column_name)
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY date;
```